# How can I block specific telephone numbers on my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

How can I block specific telephone numbers on my iPhone? I don't want to get call from specific numbers. if anyone call to me from the blocked number, he should receive a message that "this number does not exist" or "this number is busy" always.

Comment: Well I have had a few phone in the past that block any individual number even UNKNOWN numbers. It should be standard on all phones. I would be harassing Apple about it and wanting my money back. That's what happens when you get an iPhone.

Comment: With the changes on iOS 7 and age of many call blocking questions, I'm going to point most of these at one simple how can I block calls question. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34157/call-blocking-for-iphone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are applications that do this if you have jailbroken your iPhone.  Without jailbreaking however there isn't a way to block a single or specific incoming number.  I've known people that have requested their provider to block a certain number and without a very good (usually legal) reason, they won't do it.

The best thing you can do is record 30 seconds of silence in garage band and then use that as a ringtone for that specific number.  Then at least the phone won't alert you.

Comment: I have a specific, audible ringtone that I use for those numbers that I wish to ignore, but silence is a great idea. I hadn't thought of that. The only downside to either solution is that the number has to be kept in the Address Book in order for it work.

Comment: +1 This is what I do. Yes, you have to add the number to the address book, but I have a group conveniently called: BlockedTards ;)

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an app that can block a number on a jailbroken phone please? As far as I know, that can *only* be handled at the carrier level.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to block a specific number where they are given a msg, "Not Available, Blocked, etc" it is free, you DONT have to have any 'reason' except that you want them blocked. Any phone co. will do it (I'm 100% sure Verizon allows FREE blocking of up to 5 lines) I simply called Verizon n said block this #, they did, it expires after 3 months automatically, but you can simply renew it.
I'de LOVE to have an app that could simple send specific numbers straight to Vm (like iBlacklist) without jail breaking my iPhone ;(

Answer (score 2):

Pay $20 and port your phone number to Google Voice.  Then Google can ignore calls from specific numbers.

Comment: This does work well, but I miss more calls through google voice as it sometimes sends the caller to google voice mail before the forwarded call rings my iPhone - not a huge deal, but might be a big drawback for some that call heavily and depend on always being able to pick up calls from people that don't know the real cell number.

Comment: GVoice is only available in the US.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you record your own message and have that respond to unwanted calls. Could be fun eg :  "All calls from this number are traced by the authorities as part of an ongoing investigation."  or  "Calls from your number are subject to $100 per minute surcharge. You have 5 seconds to hang up before charges commence."

Comment: :) how to do that?

Comment: You can't have a voicemail message that responds only to certain numbers.  So the problem with this solution is that everybody who gets the voicemail will hear this.  Not sure that my mother would want to hear this :)   That said, its not a bad solution in the short term if the pest that calls is doing it often.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you can do is call your provider and ask them to block the number for you. 
There may be apps available in the app store that can do this though.

Comment: no apps available