# Block calls from unknown and withheld

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I block calls from the "Unknown" caller? I have iOS 7 on an iPhone 4S. Does any other version of the iPhone offer this ability?

I've checked the question *[Call blocking for iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34157)*, but it doesn't seem to work for "Unknown" callers.

I found the following question: *[Cannot answer unknown calls on my new iPhone 4S](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42881)*.

I want to do the opposite. I want to stop unknown callers from coming up on the phone, and I would rather not know that they are calling.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320565/block-all-unknown-numbers-not-in-my-contacts-from-calling-and-messaging-on-my-ip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but true call blocking can be only done by a carrier. However, if you wish to allow calls only from your contact list, and exclude everyone else, you can use Do Not Disturb feature on your iPhone 4s.

Comment: This answer turned up when I was doing a search for a scenario where I am receiving numerous calls "for the vehicle owner" (presumably organized crime) coming from a number with my area code. This question and answer provide a way to only have it ring when someone from my contacts calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as of 2021 iOS can block unknown (not in address book) calls completely
or use external apps to look-up for phone numbers

See https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207099

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For saved contacts, its easy task to block any contacts from Settings > phone > blocked option.

But for Unknown number call block follow the below steps,

Phone app > Recent > (i) symbol > Recent option (Blue watch icon) > Block this caller.

Comment: Phone app > Recent > (i) symbol > Recent option (Blue watch icon) > Block this caller. That suggestion does not work. When you Hit the Clock symbol the second time nothing happens. I believe your service provider needs to have this function; AT&T does not, unfortunately.