# Block all unknown numbers not in my Contacts from calling and messaging on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, phone.app

I know I can block a number from messaging/calling me, but I can only do this after the event. Is there a way I can stop unknown numbers from messaging/calling before the event, i.e. for numbers that aren't in my Contacts list? My iPhone is running iOS 11.2.6.

Comment: Note that if you have AT&T they have a (free) app called "Call Protect" which does a credible job of doing just that. Sometimes those calls actually ring through but they are shown as "Telemarketer" or "Potential Fraud," etc... highly recommended (if you have AT&T...)

Comment: AT&T's Call Protect app/feature is powered by Hiya. If you don't have AT&T, there are two apps by Hiya, which are Mr. Number, a spam call blocking app, and the eponymous Hiya app, a caller ID and reverse number lookup system. Both use the built in PhoneKit iOS features to ID and block calls.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for...One day you will get a phone call from an automated doctor appointment reminder system (the numbers of these automated systems change without notice) and your phone will block it so you might miss your appointment and pay a no-show fee.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: if an intercepted call is legitimate, like a doctor's appt reminder, they'll leave a message. Telemarketers or spammers just hang up.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I sometimes get calls from the doctor himself, and I want to be able to answer, rather than calling back. These calls are placed from a telephone number several numerals different from the doc's main office number: the main office number ends in -00, and he calls from -03 or -04. I addressed this issue by adding the numbers he uses for outgoing calls into my Contacts. Now when the doc calls, the screen displays his name and I answer, saving the call-back-and-leave-a-message routine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, albeit with some trade offs. See [this link](https://www.macworld.com/article/3214636/ios/how-to-block-all-calls-except-those-from-your-contacts.html) for some information. If you go to Settings, hit **General** > **Do Not Disturb** > **Allow Calls From** and select Contacts Only. This setting applies to SMS messages as well. Hopefully this is useful.

Comment: Thank you, its a shame that there just isn't an option to block within the messages setting if not from a stored contact. Ah well

Comment: @M-Sync No problemo! i hope it works.

Comment: If one does this, is there then an easy way to *really* turn on Do Not Disturb (for all calls/texts)? Does one have to go through the whole menu again?

Comment: The fundamental issue with this solution is that DnD silences the phone.  Apple really needs to address this.  I want the phone to be have normally, and ring, I simply never want calls from messages from people not in my contact list.  This shouldn't be a DnD setting.  DnD is for meetings, sleeping, movies, etc.  The problem with block this caller is that I'm not getting so many spam calls that I block the number and they call back with a different last 4 digits, and I think they are CID spoofing anyway.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You can create a contacts group and add all (or desired) contacts to that group.</strike>

On your iPhone, enable **Do Not Disturb**. Go to Settings app → Do Not Disturb and select <strike>the group</strike> **All Contacts** from within **Allow Calls From** section under **Do Not Disturb**.

You can also create a Contacts group to selectively segregate contacts. To create a contacts group, refer to the Apple Support article, [iCloud: Create a group and add contacts to it](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2667).

**Update**: Apparently an easier approach is to select **All Contacts** in the aforementioned step, instead of creating a group and selecting it. All Contacts option is available by default.

Comment: Thank you, its a shame that there just isn't an option to block within the messages setting if not from a stored contact. Ah well